# Splitting a line in Notepad++ [split the line when the last numeric in the line is found]

Tags: notepad++

i would want to split a line in notepad++ ,

would want to split the line when the last numeric in the line is found

for example , input file:

```
123456chennai2  
6757H01
56789chju
```

output:

```
123456
chennai2  
6757
H01
56789
chju
```

please suggest me how could i achieve this

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\d\K(?=[^\d\r\n])`
- Replace with: `\n`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\d          : a digit
\K          : forget all we have seen until this position
(?=         : positive lookahead, make sure we have after current position
  [^\d\r\n] : NOT a digit or line break
)           : end lookahead
```

**Replacement:**

```
\n          : linefeed, you may use "\r\n" if needed
```

**Result for given example:**

```
123456
chennai2
6757
H01
56789
chju
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , but when use this expression i get as "Zero length match"

Comment: @susin: Strange. What version version of Npp are you using? Here it works with `v7.5.6 (32-bit)`

Comment: i am too using the same 7.5.6 32  bit

Comment: @susin: May be you haven't shown a real extract of your file, for the given example, it works fine. Edit your question and add a real test case.